# Do we consider Android phone's in built memory as internal storage or external storage?

Tags: android, android-file, android-external-storage, internal-storage

Android documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) says that:

"Every Android-compatible device supports a shared "external storage" that you can use to save files. This can be a removable storage media (such as an SD card) or an internal (non-removable) storage. Files saved to the external storage are world-readable and can be modified by the user when they enable USB mass storage to transfer files on a computer."

This means that the inbuilt memory is also considered external but the same documentation also says:

"In order to read or write files on the external storage, your app must acquire the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE system permissions"

I am able to read the content of internal storage without asking for any permissions in my manifest.xml file. I am using the following code to do so:

```
File currentFolder =  new File("/");
File[] subFiles = currentFolder.listFiles();
scanner= new Scanner(subfiles[0]);
String line = scanner.nextLine();
Log.i("blah", line);
```

Aren't these two statements contradictory? Is inbuilt storage internal or external?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are accessing is the internal storage of your device.

If your device has no SD card, your external storage is a folder inside of the internal storage (I don't quite remember but it's something like `emu`).